# Macro to format charts

Tags: excel, vba

This is an excerpt of the code from the full macro. It operates correctly in most cases, however the color formatting is not applied when there is only one data series.

```
Sub fullPageLine()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim chart As chart

'Data range for the chart
'Set rng = Selection
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
'Create a chart
Set cht = Selection

    'Format x axis
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        With Selection
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
        End With

    'Format title
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 8.4
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Left = 0
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Top = 2
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
        With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font
            .BaselineOffset = 0
            .Bold = msoTrue
            .Size = 8.4
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Caps = msoAllCaps
        End With

    'Format legend
        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
            .NameFarEast = "Arial"
            .Name = "Arial"
        End With
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7

    'Change chart series fill color
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
```

The first data series should be in orange, and is whenever there are 2 or more lines on the chart. However, if it is a single line chart, it shows up in the default blue rather than orange. I am new to vba, and am aware that I need to get rid of select and activate, but am trying to get the base code to work first.

Comment: Which of those `msoThemeColor` is "blue" and which is "orange"?

Comment: None are blue, which is most of my confusion. The first is orange, the second is black, and third is grey

Comment: This code is raising error if there is only one series. You should provide correct code that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: The code would give me a "400" error, but still produce the desired chart in regards to font and legend/title formatting, just the incorrect color

Comment: I get a 1004 error on `FullSeriesCollection(2)` (the parameter is not valid)

Comment: Thats odd, I don't have that issue.

Comment: Is there any explanation that you see for the problem I've described?

Comment: Actually, I get a 1004 at `ActiveChart.Legend.Select` because the chart with single series does not have a legend by default. So, the procedure fails at that point which is *before* you apply the color to the series.

Comment: So that would seem to explain it. You're not handling your errors and/or not properly handling the chart, and you're for whatever reason that assuming exit on error is equivalent to "the macro ran successfully". It didn't. It didn't get to the line that assigns the color to series 1.

Comment: oh ok, thank you, I appreciate it. As I said, I am very new to VBA

Comment: A note about setting colors:  Set your colors explicitly using RGB values.  Using theme colors ("msoThemeColorAccent2") means that if your theme changes, then so do your colors.  RGB values gives you a 100% consistent result.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro fails *before* assigning colors when there is only one series, because a chart with one series, by default, does not have a Legend.

Ensure that you have a legend in the chart (alternatively, use conditional logic to check whether Legend exists) before attempting to format the Legend.

Cleaned up to use object variables appropriately, and do your series formatting in a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fullPageLine()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As chart
Dim i As Long, color As Long, bright As Double
Dim srs As Series

'Data range for the chart
'Set rng = Selection
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).chart
'Format x axis
With cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 7
End With
'Format title
With cht.ChartTitle
    .Font.Size = 8.4
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 2
    With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoTrue
    .Size = 8.4
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Caps = msoAllCaps
    End With
End With

'Format legend
cht.HasLegend = True
With cht.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
    .NameFarEast = "Arial"
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 7
End With

' ALTERNATELY, instead of forcing the legend as per above:
'If cht.HasLegend Then
'    With cht.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
'        .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
'        .NameFarEast = "Arial"
'        .Name = "Arial"
'        .Size = 7
'    End With
'End If


'Change chart series fill color

For i = 1 To cht.FullSeriesCollection.Count
    ' Get the color based on series index
    Select Case i
        Case 1
            color = msoThemeColorAccent2
        Case 2
            color = msoThemeColorText1
        Case 3
            color = msoThemeColorBackground1
            bright = -0.5
    End Select
    ' Assign series color formats
    '## NOTE: This only works for the cases defined in the above Select statement.
    Set srs = cht.FullSeriesCollection(i)
    With srs.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = color
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = bright
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I had previously used this line of code to resize the chart: 'ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleWidth 1.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft ......                                                                                                                          
How would I do so using your corrected format? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Probably `cht.Parent.ScaleWidth ... `

Comment: Thats what I had tried but would get an "object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Shapes(cht.Parent.Name).ScaleWidth 1.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft` seems to work.  Alterantely: `cht.Parent.ShapeRange(1).ScaleWidth 1.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft`